# Is it possible to play this difficult trill on violin?

Tags: violin, trills, double-stops

There is a line in my violin music where there are two voices:

1. The higher voice is a trill G-Ab on the E string
2. The lower voice is a continuously held Db on the A string held throughout the trill

How would I play the trill while holding the Db? Is it even possible to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just tried it - it's a very awkward thing to play on a violin (easy on a guitar, though)

I used my ring finger on the A to hold the Db, and then use first and index fingers to trill on the E string. It's an annoying stretch, and getting the index finger in there is not comfortable at all.

Are the two voices there supposed to be played on the same violin? I would expect them to be played on two separate violins.

Comment: It’s for one violin. Does your trill sound smooth, or is it so uncomfortable that it your hand simply can’t do it consistently?

Comment: I can just about make it smooth, but not very fast and not for long. But I am out of practice so a more proficient violinist will find it easier.